# iOS/Swift x509 certificate, sign string

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, signing, pkcs#7

I have x509 certificate (.crt) and private key (.key)
I need to sign some string using a certificate in PKCS#7 detached signature(UTF8)

Can you explain how to distribute certificate (key) and sign?

UPDATE: it seems that i need analog of Cryptographic Message Syntax Services for iOs
Is openSsl only one way to sign message using certificate?

Comment: Finally figured out this case. To sign using this algorithms i had to include openSsl library into my project. We decided to sign on server side. There is easy to use API in .net to sign PKCS#7 detached signature(UTF8).