# How to sign with private Key in X509certificate by RSA

Tags: swift3, rsa, private-key

Newbie here. I am tasked to handle `x509certificate` in swift. It seems this `x509` thing sounds scary. I try my best to describe what I want to achieve. Hope you can guide me.

**Below is what I try to achieve:**

> 1) I would like to know, what I need in Swift to handle the
>   x509certificate p12 file and private Key 
>  2) How to Sign with
>   private key by RSA

**In C#, below code is to get a private Key**

```
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider UsePrivateKeyFromP12(string certFileName, string pwd)
{

var privateCert = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificateFileName), password);

 return (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCert.PrivateKey;
}
```

How would I do in Swift? The private key will be on the client side.

Thanks

Comment: you need the support of `open ssl`. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227984/ios-swift-x509-certificate-sign-string, and this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489391/generate-base64-url-encoded-x-509-format-2048-bit-rsa-public-key-with-swift

Comment: @Anuradh, the links have no mention of getting the PrivateKey and using RSA to handle the private key.